# Why does the map skip the first character?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to print the first occurence of each character in a string.

My code works, but for some reason it doesn't record the first occurence of the very first character of my string. 
I am using a map for this purpose(not the most ideal way, but I am trying to learn how to use them).

Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    cin.ignore();
    while(t--){
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        map<char, int> m;
        for(int i=0; i<s.size();i++)
            if(!m[s[i]])
                m[s[i]]=i;
        for(auto i: m)
            cout<<i.first<<"-"<<i.second<<' ';
        cout<<endl;
        m.clear();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2
geeksforgeeks
geeks for geeks
```

My output:

```
e-1 f-5 g-8 k-3 o-6 r-7 s-4 
 -5 e-1 f-6 g-10 k-3 o-7 r-8 s-4
```

Expected Output:

```
e-1 f-5 g-0 k-3 o-6 r-7 s-4 
 -5 e-1 f-6 g-0 k-3 o-7 r-8 s-4
```

Comment: It's not ignored. But `if(!m[s[i]])` can't distinguish between a character at position 0 from a character that hasn't been inserted yet. The first occurrence get overwritten the next time the letter comes up. Try it with an input where the first letter is never repeated like "Hello world!".

Comment: Ok, yes. For "Hello World", it doesn't get overwritten. But why so?
Sorry, but I didn't catch the explanation.

Comment: `!m[s[i]]` is the same as `m[s[i]] == 0`. When the first letter gets added, it's set to `i` which is 0. The next time that letter comes up, `m[s[i]]` will be `0` (the first letter) so it will be overwritten by the current `i`.

Comment: You can use `map::count` instead. It'll return 1 if the element already exists in the map and 0 otherwise.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  Also, you should be including the *standard* headers for the types you use - `<bits/stdc++.h>` is a GCC *internal* header that's completely non-portable (and inefficient).